# Java Robot launched from Windows System Tray

Tags: java, swing, awt, awtrobot, system-tray

I'd like my program to perform a screen capture from a System Tray menu.

I got it to work, but the MenuItem itself does not hide fast enough and is captured along with the rest of the screen.

Here's a MCVE, based on a stripped down version of The Java Tutorial's TrayIconDemo sample:
(Edit: made even more minimal thanks to Holger's comment)

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

public class TrayCapture {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    createAndShowGUI();
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() throws Exception {
        //Check the SystemTray support
        if (!SystemTray.isSupported()) {
            System.err.println("SystemTray is not supported");
            return;
        }
        final PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu();
        final TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(ImageIO.read(new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCF8S.png")));
        trayIcon.setImageAutoSize(true);

        // Create a popup menu components
        MenuItem captureItem = new MenuItem("Capture");
        MenuItem exitItem = new MenuItem("Exit");

        //Add components to popup menu
        popup.add(captureItem);
        popup.add(exitItem);

        trayIcon.setPopupMenu(popup);

        SystemTray.getSystemTray().add(trayIcon);

        captureItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    File outputFile = new File("capture.png");
                    ImageIO.write(new Robot().createScreenCapture(
                            new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize())),
                            "png",
                            outputFile);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Screenshot saved to: " + outputFile.getAbsolutePath());
                }
                catch (AWTException | IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        exitItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                SystemTray.getSystemTray().remove(trayIcon);
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And here is a resulting capture.

[image: Capture including the menu item]

As you can see, the PopupMenu is closed but the "Capture" MenuItem was still visible when the Robot took the capture and is part of the captured image.

Is there a way to force a repaint to hide the MenuItem or get a notification when it's hidden so I can make sure the Robot will not pick it up ? I'd rather avoid an arbitrary Thread.sleep() because it's just a blind race condition...

KR, Vicne

Comment: Wrap your code where you take the screenshot with `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`. This will allow the popup to be closed.

Comment: The menu has been closed. What you see is a fade-out effect created by Windows itself for the selected menu item. When you look closely, you’ll notice that all tray icon menus have this effect, regardless of the application. I don’t know of any way to find out whether an animation performed outside your own application has ended. As a side note, `createScreenCapture` does already return a `BufferedImage`, which makes half of your code obsolete, you only need `ImageIO.write(new Robot() .createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize())), "png", outputFile)`

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://superuser.com/a/861587/780223). There exists also this setting at Windows 10. Go to `Control Panel` --> `System and  Security` --> `System` and then *advanced settings* or something... I found the path, but I don't know how it is translated in english. I know, this wont answer the question though. I didn't try it, but it may help.

Comment: @weisj: Tried `invokeLater()`, to no avail :-(

Comment: @Holger: Oh, Windows animation, nice catch. I guess sleeping is the only option then :-( . And indeed the image copy code was redundant, don't know what I was thinking. I fixed it. Thanks

Comment: @gthanop: Indeed, disabling that "Fade out" option makes the issue disappear. Of course I cannot request that all users disable that option, So I guess `Thread.sleep()` will be the only option. Now remains the question of the animation duration (any idea ?). At least the advanced settings do not allow users to customize that duration ;-) Thanks.

Comment: After a bit of trial and error, after 250ms there's still a trace of the menu, but after 300ms it's completely gone. So 300 it will be. Thanks to all. @Holger, do you want to post your info (along with the delay) as an answer so I can accept it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an artifact of your Java application, as it is a Windows-specific animation of the selected menu item that continues while the popup menu is already closed.

As far as I know, there is no way to monitor the animation progress from the Java side (apart from capturing the screen and looking whether the artifact is still there).

The best option is to have a configurable delay (with a reasonable default of, e.g. 300 ms) before doing the screenshots. All screenshot tools I know of, use a configurable delay anyway.